# Vb.net Space And Word Count

Tags: vb.net

I am able to find the space count in my example but I want to find the amount of characters after the last space. How I can do it ?

For Example String :"Hello EveryBody"

There is a one space and to the right of the word is : "everybody" and it has 9 characters .

How can I do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What output do you expect for the string "Hello Every Body" with 2 spaces?

Comment: the string "Hello Every Body" has 2 spaces and there is the latest space rigt to writing body. How can I do find "body" word count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim str = "Hello Everybody"
dim startPos = InStrRev(str, " ")
dim subString = str.Substring(startPos)
dim len = subString.Length
```

len will contain 9 in this case. Is this what you're looking for?